# Why in tag edits, only the full wiki is approved, and excerpt/usage rejected?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug

It has apparently happened more than once.

I've supplied both the "little thing" and the "big thing" for the tag, and only the big thing gets approved, with the little thing being washed away.

Happened with at least taa, prima-facie, prima-facie-speed-limits.

Why is only approving the extended wiki, and rejecting the excerpts?  Shouldn't it at least be possible to see your non-approved and rejected edits, so that they could be resubmitted?

Answer (score 2):

In your profile, you can check the edits you've suggested.

Go to **Activity > all actions > suggestions**

[image: all actions - suggestions]

If you click on the **rejected edit** or **approved edit** links, it'll take you to the page where you can see the reviewer(s) and their reasons for declining your edit (or if they've **improved and edited** your suggestion).

[image: some tag wiki edits]

I can speak to some of your rejected tag wiki *excerpts* - I tend to reject excerpts that don't contain usage guidance, which is their primary purpose.

---

There's some further information on tag wiki excerpts, [from the SE blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/). which has since been codified in [the help center](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts).

[My review history is public and anyone can see it](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/58/jimsug?tab=activity&sort=reviews). For what it's worth, I've reviewed many excerpt suggestions, and I have rejected a number of them, whether they include *For questions that* or not - it's not the deciding criteria.

There *is* [a MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116752/should-tag-wiki-excerpts-include-for-issues-relating-to/116754#116754) that states that this isn't necessary, and is clutter - certainly I agree, and anyone that wants to reword these excerpts is welcome to do so.

Essentially, however, the tag excerpt is the first, and sometimes *only* information about a tag that users see when tagging a question. If users can use them appropriately when they're composing their questions, then that saves time for everyone in the long run, as we won't need to edit those questions.

Also, later down the track, it'll save a lot of time as gold tag-badge holders can single-handedly close questions originally tagged with their gold tag badge - this doesn't work if people are using the wrong tags.

Right now, only a handful of users - if, in fact, it's not just moderators - can approve tag wiki edits. This means that we really do need to make the call on tag excerpts.

I find myself asking now whether my actions were contrary to the guidelines in the help center, and whether they were harmful to the community, both those who have suggested edits, and at large. If so, I acted wrongly, and deserve censure. If not, I stand by my actions.

Comment: so, it was you who were rejecting all excerpts that don't start with "for questions relating to"?  this is absolutely ridiculous and outrageous!

Comment: @cnst Please see the clarifications I've added; I'm happy to address any additional concerns you may have.

Comment: @cnst: This is a tricky and unsettled question, which I just opened for discussion at http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/q/256/10

Comment: Tag wiki excerpts on Law have also been discussed in [this question on the main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264546/what-conventions-should-apply-to-tag-wiki-excerpts)